# MSQL before insert, update trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Trying to make a befor update, insert trigger that would set the Age column's value based on calculation from the DateOfBirth. But I seem to be missing something

```
create trigger calcAge before insert on BoardMember 
for each row 
begin 
set NEW.Age = YEAR(CURRDATE()) - YEAR(BoardMember.DateOfBirth)
end;
```

Comment: Yes, you are missing to tell us what you want to achieve and what goes wrong along the way

Comment: He/She is trying to calculate the age from the date of birth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to calculate the age automatically from the date of birth in the row of data before insertion. So your code should be like:

```
delimiter //
create trigger calcAge before insert on BoardMember 
for each row 
begin 
set NEW.Age = YEAR(CURRDATE()) - YEAR(IFNULL(NEW.DateOfBirth,CURRDATE()));
end//
delimiter ;
```

I used `IFNULL` to get the current date if the date of birth is null.
**Noticed** how `BoardMember.DateOfBirth` is replaced with `NEW.DateOfBirth` you made an error here. ***New*** is used to reference the row of data which is to be inserted into the table.

For more information see [Create Trigger in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx)